# push package builded in Gitlab CI.Runner to Nexus repository

Tags: nexus, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In Gitlab issue #19095 it's decided to leverage GL as package repository, but what should i do just now, until it's not done, for task: "try that Gitlab instead Jenkins+Nexus". From which place can I push package to Nexus?

1. from gitlab-ci.yml
2. using uploaded package from Runner using artifacts parameter gitlab-ci.yml https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/22/gitlab-8-2-released/
3. from Docker image using Maven may be
4. via webhook
5. using release tag?

Comment: Hi; I made a little edit to your question to make the numbered list show up correctly. Remember to review your question and [edit] it again if it's not quite right; in particular, please look at the [ask] guidelines to help you construct a good question.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer I think you're going to find is that you need to write it into your gitlab yml script

```
NEXUS_USERNAME=admin 
NEXUS_PASSWORD=admin123 
NEXUS_SERVER=server.com/yourserver
NEXUS_REPOSITORY=raw 
echo "Sending backup to server"

curl -v -u ${NEXUS_USERNAME}:${NEXUS_PASSWORD} --upload-file ${UPLOAD_FILE} http://${NEXUS_SERVER}/repository/${NEXUS_REPOSITORY}/${UPLOAD_FILE}
```